# на конструктор по умолчанию для нельзя ссылаться, так как эта функция удалена

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Писал код, вроде все правильно но появилась ошибка. Об'ясните пожалуйста что делать.Код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <windows.h>
    
using namespace std;
    
struct AEROFLOT
{
    string NAZN;
    int NUMR;
    string TIP;
    int TRANS;
    union TIME {
        TIME() {}
        ~TIME() {}
        string NAZV;
        bool TIM;
    } TIME;
};
    int main()
    {
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        AEROFLOT AIPORT[7]; /*Ошибка в этом месте. на конструктор по умолчанию для "AEROFLOT" нельзя ссылаться, так как эта функция удалена*/
        int n = 0, i;
        string nazva;
        while (n < 7)
        {
            cout << "Внесіть данні по рейс згідно його номеру "
                << n + 1 << ":" << endl << "Введіть назву пункту призначення: \n";
            cin >> AIPORT[n].NAZN;
            cout << "Введіть номер рейсу: \n";
            cin >> AIPORT[n].NUMR;
            cout << "Введіть тип літака: \n";
            cin >> AIPORT[n].TIP;
            cout << "Літак з пересадками?(Так - 1, ні - 2): \n";
            cin >> AIPORT[n].TRANS;
            if (AIPORT[n].TRANS == 1) {
                cout << "Введіть пункт пересадки: \n";
                cin >> AIPORT[n].TIME.NAZV;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Введіть час польоту: \n";
                cin >> AIPORT[n].TIME.TIM;
            }
            n++;
        }
        cout << "Введіть назву потрібного вам рейсу: ";
        cin >> nazva;
        n = 0;
        while (n < 7)
        {
            if (AIPORT[n].NAZN == nazva) {
                cout << "Потрібний вам літак: \nПункт призначення:" << AIPORT[n].NAZN << "\nНомер рейсу: " << AIPORT[n].NUMR << "\nТип літака: " << AIPORT[n].TIP;
                if (AIPORT[n].TRANS == 1) {
                    cout << "\nРейс з пересадкою в пункті - " << AIPORT[n].TIME.NAZV << "\nГарної подорожі!";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "\nРейс без пересадок. Час подорожі становить: " << AIPORT[n].TIME.TIM << "\nГарної подорожі!";
                }
                    break;
            }
            else {
                i = 0;
                i++;
                if (i == 7)
                    cout << "\nПотрібного рейсу немає в базі. Гарного дня!";
            }
            n++;
        }
        system("pause");
    }
```

После ответа я исправил код и появилось несколько проблем, из-за чего работа программы прерывается когда наступает момент объединения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для `union` не имеется конструктора по умолчанию, так что и `AEROFLOT` неизвестно как создавать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка достаточно прямолинейна - все используемые объекты должны быть инициализированы. И если у `std::string` и так есть нетривиальный конструктор по-умолчанию, то все `int` и `enum` остаются неициализированы. В случае `enum` еще дополнительно надо отслеживать активное поле и еще и явно его разрушать:

```
struct AEROFLOT
{
    string NAZN;
    int NUMR;
    string TIP;
    int TRANS;
    union TIME {
        TIME(void): TIM{} {}
        ~TIME(void) {}
        string NAZV;
        bool TIM;
    } TIME;

    AEROFLOT(void)
    : NAZN{}
    , NUMR{}
    , TIP{}
    , TRANS{}
    , TIME{}
    {
        return;
    }

    ~AEROFLOT(void)
    {
        if (TRANS)
        {
            TIME.NAZV.~string();
        }
        else
        {
            TIME.TIM.~bool();
        }
        return;
    }
};
```

Соответственно и при каждом изменении поля надо будет разрушать текущее поле и инициализировать другое:

```
if (AIPORT[n].TRANS == 1)
{
    cout << "Введіть пункт пересадки: \n";
    AIPORT[n].TIME.TIM.~bool();
    new (::std::addressof(AIPORT[n].TIME.NAZV)) ::std::string{};
    cin >> AIPORT[n].TIME.NAZV;
}
else
{
    cout << "Введіть час польоту: \n";
    cin >> AIPORT[n].TIME.TIM;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для `union` не имеется конструктора по умолчанию, так что и `AEROFLOT` неизвестно как создавать...

Можно, конечно, явно дописать конструктор-деструктор:

```
union TIME {
    TIME(){}
    ~TIME(){}
    string NAZV;
    bool TIM;
} TIME;
```

и все заработает, но поясните мне, зачем вы используете объединение? Что оно вам дает, кроме лишней головной боли? Экономия памяти? по сути никакой. А сложностей — хотя бы с теми же конструкторами-деструкторами — хватает.

Comment: Условие лабораторной использование объединений.

Comment: А, тогда другое дело...

Comment: видимо и преподаватель предлагал использовать char*/char[] вместо string (а так оно  будет работать и без "дополнительных конструкторов")

Comment: это не "проблемы", это предупреждения. Но да, иногда они могут стать большими проблемами.  Но конструктор для структуры AEROFLOT я бы написал

Comment: Если уж делать конструктор / деструктор, то стоит в нем что-то инициализировать / разрушать.